# pgfplots: Adding vertical lines with labels to a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wanted to replicate the following graph in latex. I'm using the pgfplots package. The main areas I'm struggling with is how to implement vertical lines with labels, how to make the tick-marker on the y-axis be absolute (i.e. have no negatives) and how to present the legend below the figure. Also disregard any slope discrepancies, my data is not equivalent to that pictured.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis on top,
    smooth,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
]
\addplot [
    domain=200:207, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{80};
\addplot [
    domain=207:220, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-80/13*x+17600/13};
\addplot [
    domain=220:250, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{0};
\addplot [
    domain=250:265, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-16/3*x+4000/3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes the y ticks positive and adds the vertical lines. There are many ways you can make the output more appealing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%axis lines=middle,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=left,
    axis on top,
    smooth,
    xlabel = $x$,
    %ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    xmax=280,
    every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
    ytick={-80,-40,0,0,40,80},
    yticklabel=$\pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%$
]
\addplot [
    domain=200:207, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{80};
\addplot [
    domain=207:220, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-80/13*x+17600/13};
\addplot [
    domain=220:250, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{0};
\addplot [
    domain=250:265, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{-16/3*x+4000/3};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{207,220,250,265}{\path (#1,0) coordinate (p-#1);}
\end{axis}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {207,220,250,265} 
{\draw (current axis.south-|p-\X) -- (current axis.north-|p-\X)
node[above,font=\sffamily]{v\Y};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thanks. One small issue is I can't work out how I can make the top line intersect at the y-axis. Extending it extends the domain of the axes. But otherwise this is great.

Comment: @Wertea Just remove `enlargelimits=0.1,`. You can add `xmax=280` instead.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for that. One last thing I notice even though you include 0 in the y-tick, it doesn't actually display 0 on the axis, do I need to add something to include 0 on the y-axis?

Comment: @Wertea An ad hoc fix: `ytick={-80,-40,0,0,40,80},` (use 0 twice).

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Wertea On my machine it does. I added the full code.